# Descriptive statistics don't seem to confirm data drift

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, drift

I'm working on a typical classification machine learning task and face with a potential data drift problem. The phenomenon is that while my model trained some "old" data set gives fine result on an evaluation subset from "old" data, but performs very poorly (heavily misclassifies one of the classes) on some "new" data.

I suspect data drift between old and new data and tried out some methods to prove it. Apart from model based approach (training another model that tries to distinguish old and new data) I tried statistical tests as well, and each confirmed data drift. However, when I actually compare drifted features (columns) in old and new data I cannot see any significant difference.

Here is an example. Kolmogorov-Smirov test gives significant difference between the same column (which is an important feature according my model) in old and new data:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import kstest

kstest(old_data[column], new_data[column])[1]
```

this gives P-value of `2.505780e-145` which reveals almost total difference. But when I check main descriptive stats, they doesn't seem actually different:

```
pd.DataFrame({"Old":old_data[column].describe(), "New":new_data[column].describe()})
```

gives:

```
           Old       New
mean  3.527651  3.406413
std   0.722752  0.689564
min   0.000000  0.000000
25%   3.000000  3.000000
50%   3.750000  3.083333
75%   4.000000  4.000000
max   5.000000  5.000000
```

Could these two columns be actually "different" despite the seemingly similarity above? I'm confused how to verify reassuringly the supposed drift.

Comment: Interesting question, although it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said, any significance test is worse than useless here, since it doesn't measure practical difference. Try looking at histograms of the variable in question, or maybe just count the number of each distinct value (since from the bits you showed it looks like it might take on a relatively small number of values). In particular, look at the variable for the subset of cases which correspond to the the misclassified class; differences for that case might get washed out by all the others.